# Guake Preferences inaccessible

Tags: gnome, guake

I have problem with configuring guake because when I try to open guake preferences it happening, but i don't know where. :(

Preferences are inaccessible, I can't get to them.

So there is my Q, is there any possible to open it in alternative way, or maybe set guake from terminal?